# Preventing Multiple POST Requests in Angular App Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular app I have a function that take in a series of user-selected filter selections and then sends out a POST request to the API, to return data filtered according to those filter selections. Those events are bubbling up from one component to another via Event Emitters:

```
<div class="page-content">
    <grid-view [records]="records"
        (sendLocation)="onReceivingSelections($event, type = 'location')"
        (sendZipcode)="onReceivingSelections($event, type = 'zipcode')"
        (sendFirstName)="onReceivingSelections($event, type = 'firstName')"
        (sendLastName)="onReceivingSelections($event, type = 'lastName')"
        (sendLanguage)="onReceivingSelections($event, type = 'language')"
        (sendBranch)="onReceivingSelections($event, type = 'branch')">
    </grid-view>
</div>
```

This is working. However, right now it is not very efficient, because each time of those filter events bubbles up, it fires off a POST request to the API. So, if I have five filters, then the function gets fired five times. Ideally I'd like to make just one POST request, once those filter selections have been gathered in total.

This is what the function that takes in the values from those event emitters looks like:

```
public async onReceivingSelections(value, type) {
    let selections = await this.filtersService.processByTypes(value, type);

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        let data = resRecordsData.data;
    };

    if (selections) {
      this.filtersService.processByFilters(
        this.page, this.pagesize, this.language = selections.language, this.location = selections.location,
        this.zipcode = selections.zipcode, this.firstName = selections.firstName, this.lastName = selections.lastName,
        this.branch = selections.branch, fn);
    }
}
```

Even though I've set this up using async/await, at present it doesn't help me, because the `processByFilters()` function will fire without waiting for "selections" to resolve with the async/await.

My question is, how can I approach this differently, so that the `processByFilters()` function only fires once "selections", which is a variable holding the result of the `processByTypes()` function, has resolved?

By the way, the two service methods being called above, look like this:

```
public processByTypes(value, type) {
  if (value && type) { this.filters[type] = value; }
  return this.filters;
}

public processByFilters(page, pagesize, language?, location?, zipcode?, firstName?, lastName?, branch?, fn?: any)
{
    return this.apiService.post({
        req: this.strReq, reqArgs: { page, pagesize, language, location, zipcode, firstName, lastName, branch }, callback: fn });
}
```

Right now, even if those filter values are empty strings, the bubbling up of those values will still result in the firing of the function with the POST request for every time an event bubbles up. So I need to somehow split this up, so that I get the values first, and the only when I have them in total will the POST request be sent over the wire.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can chain together promises, so that only once I have selections resolved will the API method get called?

What would be even better is if I could pass in all of the event-emitted filter values as an array. That would limit the firing of the API POST request to one time. But I'm not sure that's possible. When I tried to use an array I got a syntax error. I don't think Angular 2 allows for this.

But maybe I can gather them into an array to pass as one POST request in the receiving component?

Comment: Can you gather all the filters on the component where the filters are sitting in and once you pass your check (maybe all filters, or couple of the filters), have a button emit the filters ?

Comment: I currently have something similar to yours but I have a lot more checks to do in the emitter. It's just insane so if you can go with not-filter-until-button-clicked, go that route.

Comment: Unfortunately, my logic is such that I can't just go by a button click. I need to somehow control how many times the POST request fires in the receiving component.

Comment: What about make the function call and cancel the last call at each function call. That mean keep the ancient logic where the input always fire the api call, store the promise in `this` and cancel it when needed.